# Symfony(2) Template file

Tags: php, symfony

Can any one tell me where `templates/layout.php` file exists in symfony ? In the tutorial its pointed to `<!-- apps/frontend/templates/layout.php -->` but i dont have apps folder in the project root but there is a folder called app but no fronted folder inside it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Symfony2, the concept of the Symfony1 `apps` folder doesn't exist anymore.  Your project is composed of a number of Bundles, which contain your entities, controllers and views (amongst other items such as assets).  In your bundle(s) is where you will find template files.

It sounds like you're trying to use the Symfony 1 tutorial with the Symfony2 sandbox/PR downloads.  You might benefit from starting with the [Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/) instead.

Comment: I m using the tutorial from [Here](http://symfonytuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/starting-up-the-project.html).And i have my bundle in src folder =>Acme ....

Comment: This tutorial is currently still under development.  If you're on [this page](http://symfonytuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/the-controller-and-the-view.html) then you will see "NOT CONVERTED TO SYMFONY2" at the top.  I suggest you go back to the Symfony2 book - it takes you through the same basics as the first part of Jobeet does.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in:

```
<your_project>/apps/<your_application_name>/templates/layout.php
```

In the tutorial example the application name is 'frontend'.

Strange that you don't have an **apps** directory.

Comment: **apps**. That's what exists, for example, in the Symfony sandbox archive.

Comment: No dont have this folder.I m using symfony2 and download it from [link](http://symfony.com/download)

Comment: You should probably make that clearer in the question then. Symfony v1 != Symfony2.